# I'd like to change a div show/hide script to use a select menu instead of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, select

## CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body,td,th {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
body form select {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
.submit {
font-family: "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans MT", "Myriad Pro", "DejaVu Sans Condensed", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: medium;
}
body form {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.submission {
margin:0 auto 0 auto;
height:500px;
width:400px;
border:#000000 solid 3px;
float:left;
padding: 20px 0;
}
.center {
margin:0 auto;
width: 812px;
}
.left{
text-align:left;
}
.right{
float:; 
}
.eighty{
width:80%;
}
.marg_20{
margin-left:20px;
}
.marg_40{
margin-left:40px;
}
.marg_60{
margin-left:60px;
}
.content{
display:none ;
}
.up20{
margin-top:-20px;
}
.signMain{
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:WhiteSmoke ;
margin:20px auto 0;
}
.test{
width: 198px;
height: 20px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 5px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center;
}
/*select
{
color: #ccc;
}
option
{
color: #000;
}
option:first-child
{
color: #ccc;
}
*/
.submitDiv {
height: 100px;
}
.signCreatorDiv {
height: 400px;
}
.namesColumn{
width:200px;
height:350px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

## javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$('select[name="Font"]').change(function () {
var idx = $(this).index();
$('.namesColumn input:text').hide().prop("required", false);
$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content').show();
$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content:lt(' + (idx + 1 ) + ') input:text').show().prop("required", true); 
})
});//]]>  

</script>
```

## HTML

```
<form action="https://im-here.foxycart.com/cart" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="center">
<!--Begin leftSide-->
<div class="submission">
<!--Begin hiddenInputs-->
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="I'm Here Notification Sign" />
<input type="hidden" name="price" value="10" />
<input type="hidden" id="productImage" name="image" value="http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/images/01.jpg"/>
<!--End hiddenInputs-->
<!--Begin colorSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
<label>Color</label>
<br>
<select id="colorSelect" name="Color" tabindex="1" required>
<option value="" selected="selected" disabled>Choose A Color...</option>
<option value="Black">Black</option>
<option value="DarkGrey">Brushed Aluminum</option>
<option value="DarkKhaki">Brass</option>
</select>
</div>
<!--End colorSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin nameSelection
<div class="left eighty center">Number Of Names
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="1{p+100}" id="Names_1" class="NameRad1 trigger textBox1" tabindex="5" required />One
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="2{p+200}" id="Names_2" class="NameRad2 trigger textBox2" tabindex="6" />Two
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="3{p+300}" id="Names_3" class="NameRad3 trigger textBox3" tabindex="7" />Three
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Names" value="4{p+400}" id="Names_4" class="NameRad4 trigger textBox4" tabindex="8" />Four
<br>
</div>-->
<!--End nameSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin columnSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">Number Of Columns
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Columns" value="1" id="Columns_0" class="ColumnRad1 " tabindex="3" required />One
<br>
<input type="radio" name="Columns" value="2" id="Columns_1" class="ColumnRad2 " tabindex="4" />Two
<br>
</div>
<!--End columnSelection-->
<br>
<!--Begin fontSelection-->
<div class="left eighty center">
<label>Font</label>
<br>
<select id="fontSelect" name="Font" required>
<option value="Arial" selected="selected">Modern</option>
<option value="Times New Roman">Classic</option>
<option value="Impact">Vintage</option>
<option value="Verdana">Retro</option>
</select>
</div>
<!--End fontSelection-->
</div>
<!--End leftSide-->
<!--Begin rightSide-->
<div class="submission">
<div class="signCreatorDiv">
<div class="signMain"></div>
<div class="namesColumn">
<div class="NameImg content">
<div class="NameTxt1 right test">
<input class="test" type="text" name="name1" id="textBox1" value="" placeholder="Name 1" tabindex="9" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content">
<div class="NameTxt2 right test ">
<input class="test" type="text" name="name2" id="textBox2" value="" placeholder="Name 2" tabindex="10" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content">
<div class="NameTxt3 right test">
<input class="test" type="text" name="name3" id="textBox3" value="" placeholder="Name 3" tabindex="11" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="NameImg content">
<div class="NameTxt4 right test">
<input class="test" type="text" name="name4" id="textBox4" value="" placeholder="Name 4" tabindex="12" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="submitDiv">
<input type="submit" name="x:productsubmit" id="productsubmit" value="Add My Sign" class="submit" tabindex="13" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<!--End rightSide-->
</div>
</form>
```

fiddle with my (failed) changes to make it a select menu
http://jsfiddle.net/EzxAj/2/

So I'd like to be able to turn on and off text areas with a select menu now instead of a radio group.  I'm sure it's my syntax but I just can't seem to make anything other than a specific # of divs show...does index not work the same way with select menus?

## Edit:

I would also like to have it default to the 3rd select item and have the 3 associated text fields visible on page load.

## Edit 2

In the actual implementation here:http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/
the divs are shown by default, and it looks like the script here: `$('.namesColumn .IH_pINameRow').show();` is the culprit...assigning a style of block to the divs...when I remove it it goes away, but obviously the script no longer works as expected either.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the index of the select menu. Instead, you need to get the selected option of the select menu.

```
var idx = $(this).children('option:selected').index();
```

Comment: Awesome!  One question, If I wanted to default to say item #3 and have 3 text fields showing how would I do that?

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/65NQN/1/

Comment: maybe something like this at the end of the window load function:     `$('select[name="Font"]').children('option').eq(2).attr('selected','selected').end().change();`

Comment: Bingo!  I will test this fully later, but at first glance it is working great.  Thanks!

Comment: this is a great implementation...however, when I put it into the actual page it incorrectly shows all of the div's containing the text fields but correctly hides any text fields numbered greater than the current selection...if I remove this: `$('.namesColumn .IH_pINameRow').show();` it starts to have the right functionality but loses the dafault selection and showing/hiding...here's the actual page:

http://2plygraphics.com/im-here/

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try chaning these: `$('.namesColumn input:text').hide().prop("required", false);
    $('.namesColumn .IH_pINameRow:lt(' + (idx + 1 ) + ')input:text').show().prop("required", true);` to `$('.IH_pINameRow').hide().children('input:text').prop('required', false);
    $('.IH_pINameRow:lt(' + (idx + 1 ) + ').show().children('input:text').prop('required', true);` - this way you are showing/hiding the divs and setting/unsetting the required class on the inputs.

Comment: seems like it should work, but I'm getting a syntax error:

`$(window).load(function(){
$('select[name="numNames"]').change(function () {
var idx = $(this).children('option:selected').index();
$('.IH_pINameRow').hide().children('input:text').prop('required', false);
$('.namesColumn .IH_pINameRow').show();
$('.IH_pINameRow:lt (' + (idx + 1 ) + ').show().children('input:text').prop('required', true);
});
$('select[name="numNames"] option:eq(2)').prop('selected', true);
$('select[name="numNames"]').trigger('change');
});`
seems like it may need an extra parenthesis...

Comment: incomplete selector. change `$('.IH_pINameRow:lt (' + (idx + 1 ) + ').show().children('input:text').prop('required', true);` to `$('.IH_pINameRow:lt(' + (idx + 1 ) + ')').show().children('input:text').prop('required', true);` . also, you should remove `$('.namesColumn .IH_pINameRow').show();` since that is making all of those divs visible.

Comment: Yay!  That worked!  Thanks, I updated with your next to last comment and they were all showing...but with the removal of the .show line it all works as it should

thanks for ALL YOUR HELP! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code that Attila suggests and changed the last line in the script to

```
$('.namesColumn .NameImg.content:lt(' + idx + ') input:text').show().prop("required", true);
```

To select item #3 by default:

```
$('#fontSelect option:eq(3)').prop('selected', true);
$('#fontSelect').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks, but the first snippet shows the incorrect amount of text fields, is using base 0 instead of base 1, hence the +1 and the second snippet looks like it might help, but it does undesireable things when added to that script...would I have to create a new script?

Comment: I put the second snippet after change method. What are the undesirable things you are getting?

Comment: adding that to the winodw load function worked...oddly enough when using attila's method I get incorrect display in dreamweaver but correct in browser...however, with yours I get perfect display in both...